# SQL - Search multiple values across multiple columns to create a flag

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to search for multiple values across multiple columns so I can create an inclusion criteria flag, but can't figure out the best way. I need to create a flag, so I am trying to not have to use a `where` statement

I have this in my code now for only one value and it works:

```
when 'a' in (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
then 1 
else 0 
end as col_a
```

Would like to do something like, but can't figure it out:

```
when 'a', 'b', 'c' in (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
then 1 
else 0 
end as col_all
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(case when 'a' in (col1, col2, col3, col4) and
           'b' in (col1, col2, col3, col4) and
           'c' in (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
      then 1 else 0
 end) as col_all
```

It is a little unclear if you want *all* to match or *any* to match.  If the latter, use `or` rather than `and`.

Comment: I have tried something similar, I have close to 100 values to search over 20 columns, so was hoping to not have to make it too long. Might be the only way

Comment: @sem you can not do what you are thinking. `case` expression/statement is evaluated for one condition at a time that's why it's `case...when`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
case array_except(array['a','b','c'],array[col1,col2,col3,col4]) 
when array[] 
then 1 
else 0 
end as col_all
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that runs, but unfortunately it doesn't properly flag any of the values (i.e. a, b, c from above)

Comment: Tested successfully on Athena (both technically and logically). Test it on a simple example and see what went wrong.

Comment: @sem - see attached picture in answer

Comment: @django-unchained -  the OP request is actually feasible :-)

Comment: I am able to do a simple example and it will work, but still trying for what I actually need. Thanks for your help!